# ffmpeg - dealing with edge blur?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to deal with Edge Blur that can occur from old bad quality footage?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBfof.png)

This image here has noticable edge blurring, is there a way to resolve this since its a cartoon style image?

You can see the edge blur on basically any edge. If you dont notice it right away, zoom in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try ffmpeg's [SmartBlur](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#smartblur-1).

Having `ls` and `lt` negative sharpens the edges.

You'll need to tweak for the source, possibly using an AviSynth script to apply different values to different sections.

Starting suggestions:

smartblur=lr=1.5:ls=-0.25:lt=-3.5:cr=0.75:cs=0.250:ct=0.5

**or**

smartblur=1.5:-0.35:-3.5:0.65:0.25:2.0